# MS SQL 2008 / в названии таблицы

Tags: sql, sql-server, pandas

пытаюсь получить данные из таблицы, таблица существует(проверено не один раз), название совпадает (проверено не один раз), как я понял (насколько моего уровня знаний хватает) проблема в самом названии таблицы.

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text

# variables
serverName = "DBTEST"

engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://user:password@X.X.X.X/TEST?driver=SQL+Server')
conn = engine.connect()

queryDiscr = text(f'SELECT * FROM "{serverName}$Sales/purch" ')
DiscrDF = pd.read_sql_query(queryDiscr, conn)
```

пробовал экранировать по разному:

```
    queryDiscr = text(f'SELECT * FROM [{serverName}$Sales/purch] ')
    queryDiscr = text(f'SELECT * FROM {serverName}[$Sales/purch] ')
    queryDiscr = text(f'SELECT * FROM "{serverName}$Sales/purch" ')
    queryDiscr = text(f'SELECT * FROM \"{serverName}$Sales/purch\" ')
```

одна и та же ошибка `Invalid object name 'DBTEST$Sales/purch'`
помогите пожалуйста с запросом.

Comment: select * from [DBTEST].[dbo].[$Sales/purch]

Comment: спасибо за ответ, та же ошибка.

Comment: вы соединяетесь с сервером? если выполнить запрос, что получаете: "select @@VERSION". Что такое у вас DBTEST?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64) 
 Apr  2 2010 15:48:46,  DBTEST  название Базы данных,  если я изменю название таблицы на другую, то запрос выполнится. т.е. можно предположить, что ошибка только в названии таблицы, но название я копировал напрямую из базы данных.

Comment: если ваша таблица в базе называется $Sales/purch и она в схеме dbo, то запрос к ней будет такой (имена в квадратных скобках): select * from [dbo].[$Sales/purch]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пожалуйста, попробуйте следующее в SSMS.

Это покажет имена таблиц и остальные детали.

```
USE DBTEST;
GO

SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;
```

Например, для базы данных AdventureWorks2019:

| TABLE_CATALOG | TABLE_SCHEMA | TABLE_NAME | TABLE_TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AdventureWorks2019 | Sales | SalesTaxRate | BASE TABLE |
| AdventureWorks2019 | Sales | PersonCreditCard | BASE TABLE |
| AdventureWorks2019 | dbo | T | BASE TABLE |
| AdventureWorks2019 | Person | vAdditionalContactInfo | VIEW |
| AdventureWorks2019 | Person | PersonPhone | BASE TABLE |